# Using Lodash to prepare dataset for an AngularJS pie chart

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I need to pass a dataset to a pie chart in an AngularJS app. The pie displays the gender of users (male and female).

The dataset must be as follow :

```
[[60, 40]]
```

The users are as follow :

```
[
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "gender" : "male"
  },
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "gender" : "female"
  }
]
```

I want to use lodash but the only function I found is countBy which does not excatly what I want. I guess it will be needed to reduce but..

This is what I tried

```
var genders = _.countBy(user, function(o) { return o.gender; })
var male = genders.male;
```

Comment: not complicated using any number of native methods that loop over an array ... don't over think it

Comment: Hum, no way to stack it in one line of Lodash functions ?

Comment: sure there is...but this is not complicated whatsoever

Comment: Something like `_.countBy(users, gender);` should return be an object with male and female values am I right ? Then I just need to access the returned object by its property ?

Comment: Actually, my stuff was working, but due to asynchronism, values were empty..

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(data, 'gender'), 'length');
```